# I need help troubleshooting why mySQL queries are taking longer than expected

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am troubleshooting why a php script takes so long to run and can sometimes time out. I have a database filled with product information (~50,000 total records) from a handful (9 total) of suppliers. The script pulls an XML file containing list of products that have changes from each supplier's feed, finds that record, then modifies it appropriately.

The query to find the single product record that matches the supplier's SKU and supplier ID in the product table is taking between 0.25 seconds and 0.5 seconds, so a small update of ~400 rows is taking over 2 minutes. I am new to database performance, and I am struggling to understand why I have a very simple query that's taking an incredibly long time to run.

I first commented out every query where it searched the database to see how long the script itself would take to iterate through the XML files. It would iterate through the 400 records in 1-2 seconds. I then added in the first query that is encountered in the iteration, which was executing the search to find the correct entry in the table for the product called out in the XML file. This is where the timing jumped to a 2 minute runtime for the script.

The iteration code, summarized for the relevant parts:

```
$checkq = "SELECT * FROM productLinks WHERE affiliateSKU=:sku AND supplierID=:sid";
$checkqs = $DBHa->prepare($checkq);

$xml = simplexml_load_file($supplierURL,"SimpleXMLElement",LIBXML_NOCDATA);
foreach($xml->children() as $products) { 
 //Set variables from the XML

 $checkqs->execute(array(':sku'=>$sku, ':sid'=>$supplierID)); //This is the problem query
 //I capture the number of results (should always be 1 or 0), 
 //and modify the entry if the result is 1, and insert a new entry if 0)
}
```

In my research for what the problem could be, I picked a random entry and ran the above query directly in phpMyAdmin and had times anywhere from 0.1 to 0.75 seconds. I used some troubleshooting steps I found while researching, but can't figure out what it really means.

I used the Explain statement, and returned the following:

```
id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | productLinks | ref  | supplierID    | supplierID | 4       | const | 11827 | Using where
```

I then ran Profile on the query, and while the query itself took 0.2218 seconds to return the 1 result according to phpMyAdmin, the Profile results returned a total of 0.00293 seconds as follows:

```
Status                Duration
starting              0.000132
checking permissions  0.000009
Opening tables        0.000007
init                  0.000011
optimizing            0.000007
executing             0.000010
end                   0.000007
query end             0.000006
closing tables        0.000019
freeing items         0.000075
cleaning up           0.000010
```

Can anyone help me understand exactly what is making my query take so long, and how I might be able to improve performance?

Comment: Are there indexes on those fields?

Comment: I have an index on SupplierID. I do not have one on the SKU because  about 60-70% of the SKUs are unique (they do not have UPC codes in these feeds, unfortunately, to help identify the same product across multiple suppliers).

Comment: I still think indexing that column would help. Admittedly, I don't really know how indexes work, just that they're a way to find stuff in a database without iterating through every entry. Indexes? Indices? Index'ses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For better performance be sure you have  a composite index on

```
table  productLinks 

columns  (affiliateSKU, supplierID)
```

Comment: Yeah, indexes! This could very well be the thing. Indexing a column (or in this case, indexing a combination of columns together) makes searches against that column (or set) go way faster because it doesn't have to look at every entry in the DB

Comment: @Stevish   . correct .. the index  reduce  the time avoiding the full scan for the table  ..and (not in this case because there is a SELECT *) can retrieve directly the data from the index  and avoid the access  to the data table

Comment: WOW! This worked perfect. I had not yet stumbled upon/learned about composite indices. I had created an index on SupplierID originally. Once I added the composite index as suggested, the run time of that query went down to 0.0007 seconds, and the script takes 1 second or less to go through all 400 records now. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's magic, I tell you! A simple index literally sped up your search 1,000 fold! It shouldn't be possible! It's magic.

Comment: I am very pleased .. good indexing is essential for obtaining and maintaining optimal performance... indexes ..are the main (foundamental) step for db tuning

Comment: Clearly. I'll certainly be doing more research to better understand indexes / indices and how to use them properly in design for future queries. Thanks again!